# is currently unable to handle this request htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel

I need help editing my httpd.conf file to run my script after installing on CWP control panel. My script run on cpanel with default settings. 
.htaccess file details:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 Apache config
 <FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|php)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `Apache config` line so your .htaccess file looks like this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 <FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|php)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </FilesMatch>
```

Use [htaccesscheck.com](http://www.htaccesscheck.com/) to check your .htaccess file syntax.